# Symfony Two edit actions (activate/desactivate) one is working and the other doesn't work

Tags: symfony

I have two actions that edit the entity 'user' attribute 'etat' : activateAction makes the 'etat' equals to 1 if it was equal to 0, else it returns a flashbag message 'the account is already activated', and the desactivateAction is supposed to do the opposite, but it doesn't work!!! Here is the code of both activate and desactivate actions:

```
/**
     * @Route("/admin/gestEtat/act/{iduser}", name="act")
     *
     * @Template()
     */
    public function activateAction($iduser)
    {
        $user=new user();
         $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $repository = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:user");
         $user = $repository->find($iduser);
               if($user)
               {
                   if ($user->getEtat()==1) {
                       $this->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add('act',"Ce compte est déjà activé!");
                       return $this->redirectToRoute('gestEtat',
                           array());
                   }
                   elseif ($user->getEtat()==0) {
                       $user->setEtat('1');
                       $em->merge($user);
                       $em->flush();
                       return $this->redirectToRoute('gestEtat',
                           array());
                   }
               }
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/gestEtat/desact/{id}",name="desact")
     *
     * @Template()
     */
    public function desactivateAction($id)
    {
        $user=new user();
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:user");
        $user = $repository->find($id);
        //$session = new Session();
        //$session->start();
        //$users=$session->get('users_table');

        if($user)
        {
            if ($user->getEtat()==0) {
                $this->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add('desact',"Ce compte est déjà désactivé!");
               // return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:gestEtat.html.twig',
                return $this->redirectToRoute('gestEtat',
                    array());
            }
            elseif ($user->getEtat()==1) {
                $user->setEtat('0');
                $em->merge($user);
                $em->flush();
               // return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:gestEtat.html.twig',
                return $this->redirectToRoute('gestEtat',
                    array());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're performing `setEtat('0')` by passing in the string '0'.  If the entity variable is a boolean, you should send it as a (true/false) or (1/0).  If it is a string, you should be checking in your code `elseif (getEtat()=='1')`

The way it stands, checking `if (getEtat()==1)` will be the same as `if (getEtat())`, which will return true if `getEtat()` is not explicitly a false/null boolean, or a null variable.